# JSONArray becomes 2D

Tags: java, json

I'm attempting to create a 1D String JSONArray and for reasons I cannot fathom It becomes 2D.

```
import org.json.*;  
...  
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
ja.put("minconf=1");
System.out.println(ja.toString());
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.accumulate("method", "getbalance");
jo.accumulate("params", ja);
System.out.println(jo.toString());
```

This Outputs:

```
["minconf=1"]
{"method":"getbalance","params":[["minconf=1"]]}
```

I dont understand how/why the ["minconf=1"] becomes [["minconf=1"]] when added to the other JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops.

The JSONObject.accumulate() method "Accumulates values under a key." [Javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)
Instead of using the .accumulate() method I should have used .put().

Adding an JSONArray via accumulate inserts it into an array straight away, however a single string value remains unmolested until the second string value is added.

```
jo.accumulate("method", "getbalance");
//Outputs: {"method":"getbalance"}

jo.accumulate("method", "getbalance");
jo.accumulate("method", "and");
//Outputs: {"method":["getbalance","and"]}
```